# Aggregating DataTable Without LINQ

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, datatable

I want to aggregate a datatables rows based on some distinct values. I have to use Select and Compute methods or other non-linq approaches. 
My question is: how can I aggregate (sum, count, min and ...) and grouping fields, and get results just like the sql server tables. Consider I have a table with four columns a, b, c, d. When I want to aggregate 'a' based on 'b, I can write:

```
Select sum(a) as 'a', b
from myTable
group by b
```

And the sql sever make a table with two columns, 'a' and 'b', so how can i do this in C# and using `DataTables`?
I saw the examples of `DataTable.Compute()` in MSDN and the other related sources for aggregating and grouping the data in a datatable, but it return just an object value and it doesn't useful for grouping rows in datatable. in my problem, the user deiced to using of `sum`, `min`, `max`, or ... at run time, and  I trying to find a solution  for creating some dynamic queries.

Comment: Why do you **not** want to use LINQ?

Comment: Using of Sum, Min, Max, Count, Avg is dynamic, an the USER  deiced how to aggregating the fields. in LINQ you haven't dynamics query (in a simple way!)

Comment: Does https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library or http://nlinq.codeplex.com/ suit your needs?

Comment: @mjwills, Thank you very much for weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/…! this is great. I seen that before, but not so this closely! Actually you saved my day!

Answer (score 0):

You should use [Dynamic LINQ](https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library). It allows you to execute LINQ based on string inputs.

[image]

Comment: Is there any complete reference for  Dynamic LINQ?

Comment: Check out https://dynamiclinq.codeplex.com/documentation and http://docs.telerik.com/data-access/developers-guide/linq-support/data-access-feature-ref-linq-support-dynamic-linq .

Comment: Actually there is no useful documentation for this library. it sounds Dynamic LINQ no longer develop since 2009. the features are so limited.
@mjwills, thank you , for your help.

Comment: The bottom of http://docs.telerik.com/data-access/developers-guide/linq-support/data-access-feature-ref-linq-support-dynamic-linq#downloading-the-linq-dynamic-query-library claims that the download includes HTML documentation. Did you have any luck with that?

Comment: Download links are corrupted. it's referring me to https://msdn.microsoft.com/vstudio//bb894665.aspx, that the address is unreachable!

Answer (score -1):

Try following :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;

namespace ConsoleApplication64
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("a", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("b", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("c", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("d", typeof(string));

            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 1, "b1", "c", "d" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 2, "b1", "c", "d" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 3, "b1", "c", "d" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 4, "b2", "c", "d" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 5, "b2", "c", "d" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 6, "b3", "c", "d" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 7, "b4", "c", "d" });


            var results = dt.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(x => x.Field<string>("b")).Select(x => new { key = x.Key, sum = x.Sum(y => y.Field<int>("a"))}).ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This uses LINQ.